# How to get a struct tag without having to instantiate the struct

Tags: go

```
type User struct{ 
    Name string `json:"name"`
}

func main() { 
    t := reflect.TypeOf(User{}) 
}
```

It is possible to capture the tag's values ​​without instantiating it. For example capturing the value of the tag "json" without having to instantiate the User structure.

Comment: Is performance the main concern here? What is the problem with instantiating the struct?

Comment: Basically "No". And: there is no reason not to instantiate a struct (e.g. in init).

Answer (score 4):

Creating a value is not a performance issue in almost all scenarios, but you can avoid creating a value by using a nil pointer value.

```
t := reflect.TypeOf((*User)(nil)).Elem() // Elem "dereferences" the pointer type.
```

The reason to use the pointer pattern shown here is that the one syntax works with every type. In particular, it handles interface types:

```
type I interface{}

// Naive developers might expect the following
// to return the type for I, but it actually
// returns nil. 
t := reflect.TypeOf(I(nil))

// The pointer pattern returns the type for I.
t = reflect.TypeOf((*I)(nil)).Elem()
```

The pointer syntax is the same for all types independent of how the zero value is written for the type:

```
t = reflect.TypeOf(User{})
t = reflect.TypeOf(uint(0))
t = reflect.TypeOf(myString(""))
```

Use `t = reflect.TypeOf((*T)(nil)).Elem()` where `T` is any type:

```
t = reflect.TypeOf((*User)(nil)).Elem()
t = reflect.TypeOf((*uint)(nil)).Elem()
t = reflect.TypeOf((*myString)(nil)).Elem()
```

Comment: This is a fun answer, and it's a good answer to the question.  But as @Volker pointed out, it's not a good idea to actually do this to avoid "having to instantiate the User structure".  `reflect` is way more intensive than instantiating a `struct`.  If you're interested in learning Go,  ignore reflection at first.  None of my production code has ever needed it.